# Vectorizing for loops for bintprog constraints in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, constraints, vectorization

I am trying to solve an LP using bintprog and have constructed all the contraints using for loops. However, this makes the process too slow so I want to write all of my loops in vectorized code but I am having trouble doing this. Here are some of the loops that i want to vectorize:

```
    A=zeros(J,J)
    for i=1:J
    A(i,i)=1;
    end



    B=zeros(((J-20)*20)+sum(1:19),J);
    for q=1:J-1
    for k=1:q
    for i=1:J-q
    B(i,i+k)=1;
    B(i,k)=1;
    end
    end
    end
```

for the first case, J=42

Can anybody help me to understand how to vectorize these? I have looked at lots of information about matlab vectorization online and haven't managed to find anything which will help.